# malformed Server Hello(TLS1.3) in Firefox

Tags: ssl, firefox, wireshark

[image: Wireshark capture]

Here is [.pcapng Wireshark file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hyu2sy36mbfruru/malformed_serverhello.pcapng?dl=0).

I made a tls Server and accessed it with firefox browser.
It returned me an Alert message and browser complains 'malformed server hello message'.
I looked at my code many times I couldn't find what is wrong.
above is the capture of the packets. What is wrong with my packets?

Comment: this may be a firefox problem.

Comment: If there is code that you have written that is relevant, please post it.

Comment: I think code will just make things complex. There is a packet capture file instead.

Comment: In 1.3, we should echo the client session id in server hello message.. I didn't know that.